# Creating a login program that recalls information from text files

Tags: python

I've recently taken an interest Python and decided to challenge myself with a simple quiz task that I found online. The full task can be found here if that makes things clearer:

"https://gyazo.com/35426cce2c0f177b37031ea6a87b2ce9"

***What I have done so far:***

1. Asked for a name, age and password
2. Created a username from the name and age entered earlier (task 1 from the screenshot above)
3. Stored the username and password into an external text file which is separated by a comma.

What it looks like so far:

```
name = input("Please enter your name. ")
age = input("Now please enter you age. ")

username = name[0:3] + age
print ("Your username has been created and is", username, ".")

password = input("Now please create a password. ")

file = open("Login.txt","a")
file.write (username)
file.write (",")
file.write (password)
file.write("\n")
file.close()

print ("Your login details have been saved. ")
```

***What I need help with:***

Basically I'm struggling to create a login program. Something that asks for a username and password, checks to see if said username and password is in the text file and if not, prompts the user to create an account by entering their name,age and password to continue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. If I haven't been clear anywhere feel free to ask where I need to be more specific as I know it's important to be 100% clear.

Comment: Noted. Edited so the code is in the post and not in a screenshot now.

Comment: You don't really need help with #1, and #2, #3 and #4 boil down to just #2. This list of specification make your question look like a 'do my hw' while it really isn't, I think. We don't need to know the whole story, just ask about what you need.

Comment: I included the numbers because I thought it would make things easier to understand by giving a little context. Regardless, it's been edited now to just what I need as you say. Thanks.

Comment: **What I need help with:**

*Basically I'm struggling to create a login program. Something that asks for a username and password,* checks to see if said username and password is in the text file *and if not, prompts the user to create an account by entering their name,age and password to continue.*

Everything in *italic* is not your real problem. Am I right?

Comment: *decided to **challenge myself** with a simple quiz task*... perhaps you should work a little more on your own if that's the case?  Solve as much of the problem any way you can with any language or technology you know first.  Then when you get hung up on a particular detail ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, your Login.txt file would look something like this:

```
some_user,some_pass
some_other_user,some_other_pass
```

In order to validate a supplied username and password, we must examine the file line by line, and then examine the different parts of the lines to determine:
a) if the username is in the file, and b) if the supplied password for the username matches.

```
logged_in = False
with open('Login.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        username, password = line.split(',')
        # Check the username against the one supplied
        if username == supplied_username:
            logged_in = password == supplied_password
            break

if logged_in:
    # Proceed to the quiz...
else:
    # Register user
```

> If not in the text file, prompts user to create an account. Then continues with the quiz as normal

You should differentiate between a username not being in the file at all (an unregistered quiz user), and a username that is found in the file, but was supplied with an invalid password. It makes sense for the former to result in registration; but not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search in the file for the record matching the data.

If a user with username `neo123` and password `secure` logged in sometime, we would expect the line `neo123,secure` to be in the file, right?

If you open the file on `r` mode and call `readlines()` you'll get a list of string, each one is a line from the file. You could use the `in` operator to check if the line is in the list, meaning it's in the file.

```
with open("Login.txt", "r") as loginfile:
    (username + "," + password + "\n") in loginfile.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic part of programming is learning to break things down to pieces, then breaking the problem down into even smaller pieces, until you have something that you can solve.  Eventually you get good enough, and experienced enough, that you see the pieces immediately.

You already have the first level breakdown shown above.  You just need to break each of the steps into something that can be done.  So your high level code is something like this:

```
def main():
    username, password = get_name_and_password()
    registered_users = read_pwdfile('pwd_filename')
    if usr_pass_registered(username, password, registered_users):
        registered = True
    else:
        registered = get_registration(username, password, 'pwd_filename')
    if registered:
        run_quiz(username)
```

Now you have four sub-problems that can be tackled independently.  They can also be tested independently so that you can join them back together with confidence.

`get_name_and_password()` you indicate you have already written code for.  Move it into a subroutine and at the end return a tuple of the two values entered.

`read_pwd(filename)` will need to open the file with the given name, read its contents into a data structure, close the file, and return the data structure.  What structure to use for your data is another part of learning to program.  Here I would suggest that you create an empty list and for each line read from the file append a tuple of `(user, pwd)` to the list.  You will want to take care of the case where the file doesn't exist, so you will need to learn to code a `try: ... except FileNotFoundError:` code block.

`usr_pass_registered(username, password, registered_users)` will iterate over
the list of registered users and, if they are found, will return True.  This will give you experience in writing a for loop that will iterate over the `registered_users` data structure.  You will also have to code a `break` in the loop when you have found the user (since there is no point in continuing to look through the rest of the file).

`get_registration(username, password, 'pwd_filename')` will ask for any further information needed to create an account, open the user and password file and append the information.  Check the documentation on the built-in function `open()` for how to open the file so you can write at the end.  Return True if they registered successfully or False if they chose not to register.  You can either ask a question like 'Do you want to register?' or you can assume that they didn't want to register if they hit return to all your additional questions.

This seems like a good challenge for a beginning Python programmer.  You will get to use a variety of code and data structures, you will learn to debug your program, and you will learn to use Python's documentation.